# Area of triangle when two sides and angle given but not in between the two sides

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

[image]

What should be the formula to replace area of triangle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint to get you started:

- First use the formula for the area of triangle

$$\frac12 ab \sin \theta$$ to determine one of the unknown side.

- After that use a different formula to determine $x$.

Comment: Thank you, will try and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Siong comment, this is my answer.

[image]